# std::vector and copy constructors

Tags: c++, gcc, stl

```
vector<X> v;
X x;
v.push_back(x); v.push_back(x); v.push_back(x);
```

Why this code calls the copy constructor of a class `X` **6 times**? (using g++ 4.7.2 STL)

Please, I'd like to know it **precisely** what happens under hood with this particular STL.

Comment: Probably, because of some rellocation (all elements of a  vector must be in a continuous block of memory)

Comment: @KirilKirov Yes, that's definitely right, but I'd like to know precisely what happens underhood.

Comment: It's implementation defined. The standard does not say anything about this, as far as I know.

Comment: try to call `v.reserve(3)`, it should reduce the number of calls to copy constructor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you insert `x` with `push_back()`, the memory is reallocated eventually to make room for the new element. The already inserted members must then be copied around using the copy constructor `X(const X&)`.

If you insert

```
v.reserve(3);
```

reallocation is prevented for at least the first three `push_back()`s and, as a result, there will be only three calls to `X(const X&)`

Comment: In general, that's right, but I provided a little bit more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vector reserve to create space in the vector before hand to speed up adding elements to a vector as well as stopping this from happening.

Comment: resize will actually create new objects, therefore calling the default constructor on the 3 new objects. push_back will add newly created objects at the end of the list, and he will end up having 6 items in his vector. reserve is what he needs here.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is that `std::vector` is implemented using the doubling-array (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) and it calls approximately `2 * N` times the copy constructor.

For example, for `N = 100,000` it calls the copy constructor `231,071` times. As it has been pointed out, the number of reallocations can be reduced by calling to `v.reserve()`.

Comment: The "right answer" is that *your compiler's implementation of std::vector* is implemented using the doubling-array. The standard requires no such thing.

Comment: @Angew I consider only gcc's implementation. See the question.

Comment: if the size of the vector doubles every time it gets too small, you incur approximately log(N) calls to the copy constructor, rather than 2*N

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens:

Before the first push_back, the capacity of the vector (the number of elements that fit in the space it has allocated) is 0. So when you do the first push_back, it allocates space for 1 item and calls the copy constructor (1st call).

So now the capacity is one, and you tell it to add another item. So it has to allocate more space, in this case, space for one more item and copy the original items to the new space (2nd call). The second push_back calls the copy constructor again (3rd call).

Now you have a capacity of 2 and tell it to add another item. So it has to allocate more space and copy the items to the new space (4th and 5th calls). Then the third push_back calls the copy constructor again (6th call).

As others have pointed out, you can use reserve, which will allocate space upfront, avoiding the need to reallocate and thus, calls to the copy constructor.